# Count() inside for-each

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm not very familiar with xslt stylesheets and I need some help. In general the goal is to check how many occurrences of 'interface" are in set of 'testcases'. My idea was to iterate over include file interfaces_list.xml and each iteration use count function with contain to check how many occurrences of particular interface is present in extendedinfo's of all testcases. Probably problem is with the context, but I don't know how to temporary change it from 'interface' to 'testmodule'. I tried code as below but counted number is 0.

```
<xsl:variable name="interface_list" select="document('interface_list.xml')" />
            
<xsl:for-each select="$interface_list/header_xml/interface">
<xsl:variable name="nameofinterface"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:variable>
    <tr>
    <td class="NumberCell" width="60"><xsl:value-of select="count(//testcase/extendedinfo[contains(.,$nameofinterface)])"/></td>            
        </tr>               
</xsl:for-each>
```

```
here I want o count occurrences:            
<testmodule starttime="2022-07-27 16:29:54" timestamp="1397.491492" verdicts="2_basic" measurementid="ad20a6c0">
   <testgroup>
    <testcase starttime="2022-07-27 16:29:54" timestamp="1397.491492">      
          <extendedinfo type="text">[12345][654321][123654]</extendedinfo>
    </testcase>
    
    <testcase starttime="2022-07-27 16:30:18" timestamp="1421.291492">   
          <extendedinfo type="text">[12345]</extendedinfo>
    </testcase>
    
    <testcase starttime="2022-07-27 16:30:42" timestamp="1445.091492">
          <extendedinfo type="text">[654321]</extendedinfo>
    </testcase>
    
    <testcase starttime="2022-07-27 16:31:06" timestamp="1468.891492">
          <extendedinfo type="text">[123654]</extendedinfo>
    </testcase>
    </testgroup>
</testmodule>
```

```
file: interface_list.xml
<header_xml>

<interface>12345</interface>
<interface>654321</interface>
<interface>123654</interface>
<interface>112233</interface>

</header_xml>
```

Comment: Which XSLT processor will you be using for this?

Comment: I'm using sabcmd

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with such processor. Which version of XSLT does it support (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153)?

Comment: It is version 1, vendor is Ginger Alliance

Comment: Is that Sablotron? I thought it was extinct...

Comment: Probably yes, it is a part of our testing software, it is used only for generation of .html testreport from output .xml.

Comment: Good software never dies; people just stop talking about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are limited to  XSLT 1.0 (with no extensions), you could do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="interface_list" select="document('interface_list.xml')" />

<xsl:template match="/testmodule">
    <xsl:variable name="testmodule" select="." />
    <table>
        <xsl:for-each select="$interface_list/header_xml/interface">    
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="count($testmodule/testgroup/testcase[contains(extendedinfo, current())])"/>
                </td>            
            </tr>               
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to get:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>12345</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>654321</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123654</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>112233</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note that this assumes one `interface` value cannot be contained in another. If this assumption is incorrect (as I would suspect after noticing that they are not all of the same length), then change the counting instruction above to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count($testmodule/testgroup/testcase[contains(extendedinfo, concat('[', current(), ']'))])"/>
```